# Email Message - From Field

Tags: email, powershell

I have a powershell script (being called by a batch file) working that is emailing a log file every night once a process is completed. However, for a variety of reasons related to SMTP/authentication, I had to use a gmail account to send it as opposed to one of our internal accounts exchange accounts (works on my PC but not on the server running the process, basically)...

Even though I have the "From" field as the *internal email*, the message arrives from the *gmail account*.

Can anyone tell me how to FORCE it to show that it came from the internal email as opposed to the account I'm using to authenticate to Google?

Thanks!

Below is the script:

```
function sendMail{

 Write-Host "Sending completion email..."

 #Creating SMTP server object, setting secure connection and specifying credentials
 $smtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient 
 $smtpClient.Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 $smtpClient.Port = 587
 $smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
 $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("*gmail account*", "*gmail password*");

 #Creating Email structure
 $emailfrom = "*internal email*"
 $emailone = "*customer email*"
 $subject = "Import Process Completed"
 $body = "To whom this may concern,

 Your import process has completed. Attached is the import log. Please check the file and contact support if you have any questions or concerns.

 Regards,
 Support"

 $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
 $emailMessage.From = ($EmailFrom)
 $emailMessage.To.Add($EmailOne)
 $emailMessage.Subject = ($Subject)
 $emailMessage.Body = ($Body)
 $emailMessage.Attachments.Add("$env:TFXLog")

 #Sending email 
 $SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `send-mailmessage` with your internal mailserver? it uses the server specified in $psemailserver and for me works without problems with our Exchange-Server? Also what mailserver are you using?

Comment: Hello @Paul. I did try that a few weeks ago initially...the issue is that from these set of 'import' servers, I cannot authenticate to that server. I can from my desk (where I initially wrote my batch file/script). Hence the 'workaround' of using our test gmail account. The reason why I want to force it to 'look' like our main support email is because the gmail account isn't very professional...lol.

I don't have access to our exchange environment, so I can't say what it is or how it's setup.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with authenticating to your Exchange? If the import servers can reach google they should be able to reach your Exchange, at least the public facing connectors. Google will not let you specify your own from address, or more specifically will allways overwrite it with your account email

Comment: @Paul, I can't authenticate to my internal exchange server from the public facing import server in the sense that I can't communicate with the server at all (refusing connection). I can't even telnet. That's why I'm forced to use a 'public' email (such as a Google account). I was hoping there was a way to override it, but it sounds like there isn't and the only way for me to get it to show the right 'FROM' address is to pray and hope that the server guy can figure out his exchange setup to allow my import servers to talk to our mail system.

Comment: So your exchange is not reachable from the internet? try to telnet to mail.yourcompanysexternaldomain.com (this of course is only an example) instead of mailserver.internaldomain this must work for the server to receive mails from the internet. if you can give me the maildomain of the server i can tell you the address you can try to connect to

Comment: What you are asking for should not be allowed if I understand what you are trying to do. You are trying to authenticate to an external server and change the from address on your mail. The SMTP server should do a lookup and check to see if you are allowed to send mail. Do you have an SPF MX record? My exchange is not exterally facing partially for this reason.

Comment: Actually i was not 100% right with google allways overwriting. You can add external addresses in gmail settings and it will not overwrite the "FROM" header. BUT it will still set the "SENDER" to the address of the gmail account. On a Standard mail client it will say "user@gmail.com on behalf of [Display Name] user@external.com"

Comment: @Paul, I can't telnet to my exchange server from this set of servers. I've tried all sorts of ports (25, 80, 587, 465)...just tells me "Could not open connection to the host, on port #: Connection failed".

Comment: @Matt, you are correct. I want the From field to show an email that ends in at*mycompanyname.com instead of at*gmail.com...even though I'm using GMail to 'handle' the email transfer via their SMTP server. I'm not sure what MX records are there, don't have any access to that stuff.

Comment: @Ilya port 25 is the right one, the question basically is if you have only tried to connect to the internal address of your server or if you also tried to connect to the external one. You can get the external address if you query e.g. Googles dns for mx records for "atmycompany.com"

Comment: @Paul, I have tried to use email.companyname.com and just companyname.com with port 25. No luck. Google did return 4 MX records for my company (all of which were companyname.com).

Comment: @Ilya try to connect to the ip addresses of the mx records since your computer will still query your internal dns for the address of companyname.com and you will probably receive the internal address from it

Comment: Okay...I'm getting somewhere @Paul. I was able to telnet to companyname.com.s6b1.psmtp.com (we are hosted on Amazon)...however now when I run my script I get the following: "Transaction failed. The server response was: No relaying allowed - psmtp"

Comment: @Ilya have you authenticated with an account that has the right to send mails from that address?

Comment: @Paul, yes I used my domain account.

Comment: hmm it seems like your company is routing the mailtraffic through a gateway (Postini), here is their troubleshooting page for this error: https://support.google.com/postini/answer/139030?hl=en. Also: did the server reply with "235 Authentication succeeded"?

Comment: @Ilya Another problem could be that the ip address you are sending from is not allowed to send mails for the domain. To fix this your admins have to create a dns TXT record with an spf entry that points to the import servers ip

Comment: @Paul. I get the following response from telnet: "220 Postini ESMTP 219 y710_pstn_c6 ready.  CA Business and Professions Code Section 17538.45 forbids use of this system for unsolicited electronic mail advertisements." I will look into the TXT and SPF DNS records with my server team. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: @Ilya have you transmitted your username and password as base64 encoded string or in cleartext?

Comment: @Ilya before you talk to your admins make sure you have done the authentication correctly, the password and username have to be transmitted as base64 encoded string. you can encode a string in powershell like this: `$string = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("username");[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($string)`. use the output of this as username / password. Here is a tutorial that covers the authentication: https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet

Comment: @Paul, I'll try that tomorrow. I was use plaintext.

Comment: @PAUL, I got the converted strings but I can't AUTH LOGIN to the server. Hmm...it did say hello back after the EHLO command.

Comment: @Ilya so it doesnt answer on auth login? then i guess you have to talk to your server guys and ask for the real external ip of the exchange server (since this is an external gateway) and depending on the security in place allow the ip of the import server to send mails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is my network/server...so the script above is fine, just not in my situation. For anyone wondering...